# Is subset of convergent sequence bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

> Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots$ be a convergent sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$. If the set $S$ consists of the (distinct) points in this sequence, show that $S$ is a bounded set.

My arguments: every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence. Every Cauchy sequence is bounded. Any subset of bounded set is bounded. Hence $S$ is bounded.

Why $S$ consists of the (distinct) points - does it matter? Are there any examples when $S$ is not bounded?

Comment: Not every problem is hard.

Comment: Every set is a set of distinct members. But not all terms in a sequence are distinct.

Comment: But a bound for the sequence is a bound for every term in the sequence, hence is a bound for any element of a set whose elements are terms of the sequence. QED. As I said, not every problem is hard.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure there were not any wired counterexamples.

Comment: But take note of Michael Hardy's comment. A sequence can have repeated values. The elements of a set are distinct.

Comment: Also, your argument assumes you already have the result that every convergent sequence is bounded. If you have that result, you don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Sequence can be thought as a function $\mathbb{N} \to X$, so it can be a constant. I just don't understand why it matters: "If the set $S$ consists of the (distinct) points in this sequence". If all points of a sequence are same then $S$ would be just a singleton set. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any convergent sequence is bounded. Let $a$ be the limit. By definition,  there is an $N$ such that for all $n \geq  N$, $d(a, a_n) < 1$ for all $n \geq N$. Then let 
$$
D = \max\{d(a, a_1), \ldots, d(a, a_{N - 1})\},
$$
which is finite since it is the maximum of a finite set of numbers. Then each $a_k$ is in the ball $B(a, r)$ where $r = \max\{1, 2D\}$. The idea is that we can bound all the  large terms by their being close to the limit $a$, and we can bound the earlier terms simply because there are only finitely many of them.

Answer (score 2):

Every Convergent sequence is bounded and we really do not need Cauchy to help us with the proof.

Let us call the limit $L$

For example if you let $\epsilon =1$, eventually for some N, you have $$ n\ge N \implies |a_n-L|<1.$$

Now the set $$\{ a_1, a_2,..., a_{N-1}\} $$is bounded because it is finite.

Also the set {$a_N$, $a_{N+1}$,....} is bounded because of $$|a_n-L|<1$$

Thus your set is bounded.